# Event click when scrolling a scrollbox on XE7

Tags: android, delphi

Does anybody have a suggewstion to stop the scrollbox from raise a click event when you touch and drag to scroll it?

Scenario:
I use a vertscrollbox with buttons as a scheduler on Android App, you can scroll up and down then click the buttons to show more information.
The problem appear when you touch and scroll the screen, when letting go a click event is generated, if it's over a button you get the information but I don't want that unless you specifically click the button.

Hope my English is clear.

Comment: I don't experience this problem you're talking about. Are you using the `OnClick` event or one of the `OnMouseDown` / `OnMouseUp` events? I'm willing to bet you're using `OnMouseUp` which triggers when the user releases their finger. But I just tested, and even that doesn't cause the issue. Perhaps you have some code doing this which we cannot see?

Comment: I'm using OnClick event of the button. 
To replicate the issue it's easy. Put a verticalscrollbox on a form, then add some buttons on it. Put showmessage('OnCLick') in buttons event then run!
Try to scroll up and down the scrollbox touching the buttons at the same time

Comment: I think I know whats happening - the user is inadvertently touching and holding the button and then scrolling up and down with their finger then when he removes the finger after scrolling the OnClick event fires on that button that was the initial point of contact? Just to clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OnTap event. It is not a perfect solution because this event don't work on Windows (so you have to use conditional defines to debug on Windows), but on at least on Android OnTap isn't raised when you scroll a box (tested on Seattle).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check if the last event was the scrolling before execute the code in showmessage('OnCLick'). for this you have to keep a static variable with history of last event(s).